# Today widget doesn't work outside Xcode

Tags: swift, ios8.1, ios8-today-widget

I successfully got a Today widget working in my iOS app. It works great when running the widget on the simulator or running on a device from Xcode. But it doesn't update if I install the app on a device and then run the widget (not from Xcode).

Has anyone else faced this issue? Is there a fix to this or is this a known bug? Any workarounds so I can have a bunch of beta testers check the app using Testflight and get the widget to work?

Using Xcode version 6.1.

Adding log statements tells me that all the correct methods are called. But after that a crash log is generated and the logs are very cryptic. This is what the console says

```
Dec  1 19:23:06 MyDevice ReportCrash[3592] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
Dec  1 19:23:06 MyDevice ReportCrash[3592] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 3591
Dec  1 19:23:06 MyDevice ReportCrash[3592] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyTest[3591]
Dec  1 19:23:06 MyDevice SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: plugin com.testsaga.MyTest-Today interrupted
```

And a device log generated during this time lists this statement (specific to my widget - there are other processes in there as well)

```
Processes Name       |            <UUID>                |     CPU Time|     rpages|       purgeable| recent_max| lifetime_max| fds |  [reason]         | (state)
MyTest <84554d9818fe3e1fafa848c3fe6a34d5>         1.459        4132                0           -          8076   50  [per-process-limit]  (frontmost)
```

Any insights? Thanks.

**I tried the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281032/46297) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you managed to resolve this issue?